# Change color and border width of input fields Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I would like to change the color and the border thickness of input fields, but I can't find the way to do this. I've tried to use _extend.less but that doesn't work. It looks like styles-m.css is overriding it. So I think I have to change styles-m.css? I've tried to add a styles-m.less but I can't get it to override. Can anyone help me?

This is what a need:

.block-search input {
    left: -300%;
    margin: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #296db6;
}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

=> Add this css code :

```
.block-search input {
 left: -300%;
 margin: 15px 0;
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid #296db6;
}
```

Now, you need to add CSS and use these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thank you ravindrasinh zala. I found a something else what looks also quit good. I've added a file called _theme.less and added:  @input-text__border: 2px solid #296db6; this had the same result i wanted.  Thx for you're answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add these variables to your theme _extend.less

@form-element-input__border-color:#296db6;
@form-element-input__border: 2px solid @form-element-input__border-color;

You can find all variables in magento root folder ->  lib\web\css\source\lib\variables

see Magento docs
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html